# Add a OnetoOne field in an already populated Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this customer model where I want to introduce a user field where the user field is
`user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

but there are already some objects in this model so if i create this one to one field then it would ask me for a default value for those objects but I cannot pass default values because it'll clash with the logic.

Old model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_website = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_address = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerShippingAddress)
    billing_address = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerBillingAddress)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

New model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_website = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    customer_email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_address = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerShippingAddress)
    billing_address = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerBillingAddress)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       #Change1
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       #Change2
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       #Change3
```

Reason

```
owner - to track who created this Customer
user - to link the Customer to User model
company - to link the company to Customer, although this connection can be find through the user who created this company
```

is it the right way to approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, however adding non-nullable fields with django is always a bit of a pain. Here is how I do it:

1. Add the fields as nullable and create a new migration:

```py
# models.py 
class Customer(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                             # No changes
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)    # Nullable
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) # Nullable
```

2. Generate an empty migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_user_app --empty
```

3. Modify the migration to set all values:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models

def fill_user_company(apps, schema_editor):
    Customer = apps.get_model('your_user_app', 'Customer')
    User = apps.get_model('your_user_app', 'User')
    for customer in Customer.objects.all():
        customer.user = User.objects.get(email=customer.customer_email)  # Make your own match logic here
        customer.company = customer.user.company
        customer.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_user_app', 'your_previous_migration_that_created_the_fields'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(fill_user_company),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(
                to='auth.User',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            ),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='company',
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                to='your_company_app.Company',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

4. Change your model to set the fields as non-nullable:

```py
# models.py 
class Customer(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      # No changes
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    # Non-nullable
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Non-nullable
```

Finally you can apply your migrations, and your new fields will be automatically created and populated.
Note that you can merge your 2 migrations file in a single one if you prefer.

Comment: i'll give it a try but just one question, don't we need `related_name` for owner and user?

Comment: I think you don't need it to define it in this case because ```user``` is a one-to-one relationship that you can parse from a User instance using ```user.customer```, while ```owner``` is a one-to-many, so you can parse it using ```user.customer_set```. I'd recommend using one to make it less confusing tho.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way to go around this, In my humble opinion, there are two options.

1. You can make it nullable by defining `null=True` and then iterate over the objects in your database manually using Django's admin portal and hook every `Customer` object to their respective `User` object, and then go back and set `null=False` in that case when you migrate it will ask you to enter a default value... any value should do the trick since you do not have any object with `None` value, so nothing will really happen.

---

2. Create an empty migration by using this command:

   `python manage.py makemigrations app_name --empty`

   Then, open the created migration file and add a data migration operation to populate the user field. This operation should be written in the migrations `.RunPython` function.

It is a hassle and all the solutions to it - at least those that I know - seem absurd.

Let us know if you found a better way to do it!